# White line down the right side of the page on the mobile site

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web

When logged into sites on the Stack Exchange network from my Galaxy S3, on either the built-in browser or Chrome, there's a white line down the right side of every page:

[image: Image showing a rogue column of whitespace down the right side of the site on the built-in S3 web browser]

The problem is even more pronounced on Chrome, with the line being about twice as thick. It also causes each page to get the dreaded *horizontal scroll bar* at the default zoom level (the above was zoomed out all the way).

Same problem on iOS 7.1.2:

[image]

This only seems to happen while logged in - when logged out the page renders fine.

Any chance this could be tidied up?

Comment: I regret not waiting another minute to take the picture. Oh well.

Comment: In my case in Chrome, the site(s) loads fine without the whitespace displayed by default. But you can zoom out to force the whitespace to display.

Comment: @StevenV Yes - that's what I'm seeing. You can also just scroll to the right and it'll show as well, which is how I first noticed it.

Comment: Reproduced - looking at it now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was an extraneous `position: relative` on an element in the topbar; next build will remove it and fix this issue.

Comment: Next build should be in the next 24 hours.

Comment: Thanks Jarrod, I'll come back and accept this once I confirm that it's fixed!

Comment: Confirmed fixed in both browsers.